# Why does KeyError appear in the string?

Tags: python

There is a line of python code:

```py
post + = "& attached_media [1] = {\" media_fbid \ ": \" somecontent \ "}"
```

The purpose of the line in essence is to add a line of text to an already existing variable.
But for some reason on this line I get an error:`KeyError: '"media_fbid"'`

Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Alternate between the ' and " quoatation mark so you can write quotation marks with in strings or use the str() function to be 100% sure your not ending your string before time

Comment: Or you can use tons of backslash escaping.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the space between backslash and quote, try:

```py
post += "& attached_media [1] = {\" media_fbid \": \" somecontent \"}"
```